# How to get the name of a file downloaded with Angular $http?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, blob

I've written code that uses Angular $http to download a file.  The name of the file is *not* specified in the URL.  The URL contains a unique identifier for the file, which is fetched from outside the application.

When `$http.get(myUrl)` is called, everything works fine; the file is retrieved and I can access it in my callback handler, but I can't see how to get the name of the file.  Capturing the raw response with Fiddler, I see this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/getFile/12345
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testfile.txt
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 20:25:49 GMT

Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet!  The contents of my file!
```

From the above, it is clear that the server is sending back the name of the file in the "Content-Disposition", but I haven't found anyway to access it within my Angular callback.  How do I get the name of the file from the headers?

**Edit in response to answer below:**
I should have mentioned before that I already tried `response.headers()`.  It returns `Object {content-type: "application/octet-stream", cache-control: "private"}`, so I still don't get Content-Disposition for some reason.  `response.headers('Content-Disposition')` returns `null`.

Comment: if `response.headers('Content-Disposition') returns null` there's clearly something wrong. The answer from @andrew works perfect

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem: Fiddler clearly shows a correct content disposition header, but none of the solutions below work: response.headers('Content-Disposition') returns null

Comment: I was able to make it work in the context of the particular task I was doing, but I don't have a good general answer.

Comment: if `response.headers('Content-Disposition') returns null` and you are using CORS in your API you need to make sure that you add this header in your response: `access-control-expose-headers:content-disposition` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504121/2069306

Comment: Add `Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.AccessControlExposeHeaders, "content-disposition");` to the request function and it will give read access to the script for this particular call

Answer (score 51):

It may be worth mentioning that in order to get the file name from the HTTP headers, extracting the `Content-Disposition` header is not enough. 
You still need to obtain the `filename` property from this header value.

Example of header value returned: `attachment; filename="myFileName.pdf"`.

The function below will extract `filename="myFileName.pdf"`, then extract `"myFileName.pdf"` and finally remove the extra quotes around to get `myFileName.pdf`.

You can use the snippet below:

```
  function getFileNameFromHttpResponse(httpResponse) {
      var contentDispositionHeader = httpResponse.headers('Content-Disposition');
      var result = contentDispositionHeader.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
      return result.replace(/"/g, '');
  }
```

Comment: You might have to adapt the first line of the function provided by @andrew, depending on your Angular version. 

`var contentDispositionHeader = httpResponse.headers.get('Content-Disposition')`

Answer (score 29):

Web API: I found that adding the following line of code into the ExecuteAsync(...) method of my IHttpActionResult implementation worked (*'response'* is the HttpResponseMessage to be returned):

```
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

Angular: I was then able to resolve the filename in angular as follows (*'response'* is the resolved promise from $http.get):

```
var contentDisposition = response.headers('Content-Disposition');
var filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].trim();
```

Comment: You still need to remove extra `""` from the file name with `.replace(/"/g, '')`:

`
let contentDisposition = response.headers('Content-Disposition');
let filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g, '').trim();`

Comment: Although you might be right with the comment, this was the solution to the original problem and thus a valid answer in that context!

Comment: for .NET Core
`app.Use((ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
`

Answer (score 16):

If you use CORS, you need to add the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" to the  response headers at server side. For example: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-filename, x-something-else`

Comment: You partially true. For CORS, server must send header as `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition`.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to some of the above answers but using a basic RegEx is how I solved it instead:

```
let fileName = parseFilenameFromContentDisposition(response.headers('Content-Disposition'));

function parseFilenameFromContentDisposition(contentDisposition) {
    if (!contentDisposition) return null;
    let matches = /filename="(.*?)"/g.exec(contentDisposition);

    return matches && matches.length > 1 ? matches[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: This is actually superior to the other answers because the other answers depend on the filename being the second token of the disposition header. If it's not for some reason, then they would return the wrong data.

Comment: Slight modification if there may be some other properties after filename: `filename=?([^;]*)`. You may also be aware of " characters then I would suggest `filename=\"?([^;"]*?)`

Answer (score 6):

Use `response.headers` to get http response headers:

```
$http.get(myUrl).then(function (response) {
    // extract filename from response.headers('Content-Disposition')
}
```

Comment: I already tried this.  I should have mentioned it before, so I appended this to my question.

Comment: Indeed, you will have to expose the header with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition`. This assumes you have control of the server side response...

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring this out.  Do I need the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" on the "preflight" response or the response that contains the actual file?

Comment: This is how you do it on a rails backend: http://jaketrent.com/post/expose-http-headers-in-cors/

Answer (score 5):

**// SERVICE**

```
downloadFile(params: any): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {

    const url = `https://yoururl....etc`;


    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(
      url,
      params,
      {
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
        observe: 'response' as 'body'
      })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(err))
      );
  }
```

**// COMPONENT**

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

... some code

  download(param: any) {
    this.service.downloadFile(param).pipe(
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {

        let fileName = 'file';
        const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        if (contentDisposition) {
          const fileNameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
          const matches = fileNameRegex.exec(contentDisposition);
          if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
            fileName = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
          }
        }

        const fileContent = response.body;

        FileSaver.saveAs(fileContent, fileName);

      },
      error: (error) => {

        console.log({error});

      }
    });
  }
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you already find solution, but I will post this answer if someone else has this problem.

Add these parameters in the success callback function from the $http request:

```
    $http.get(myUrl).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // extract filename from headers('Content-Disposition')
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If `response.headers('Content-Disposition')` returns null, use `response.headers.**get**('Content-Disposition');`.

The rest of @andrew's snippet now works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
success(function(data, status, headers, response,xhr) {
    console.log(headers('Content-Disposition'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of other good answers here - here's what I ended up with that worked best for me against an ASP.NET Core 3.1 server, using a lot of these as a guide.

```
function getFilename() {
    const header = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition");
    if (!header) {
        return null;
    }

    let matches = /filename=\"?([^;"]+)\"?;?/g.exec(header);

    return matches && matches.length > 1 ? matches[1] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here and in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40939380/633721) solve OP's specific case or are even more general. I believe that you should start with [`parse` function](https://github.com/jshttp/content-disposition/blob/f3ea869a40dabd98bd8e61b177037e97ba7d212e/index.js#L314) from [`content-disposition`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-disposition) npm package. But since I failed to make this package work in my Angular 12 app (even with attempts analogous to [this comment](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/769#issuecomment-849573463)), and other answers here don't satisfy my cases, I've created yet another function.

My flag case of a filename is `Tyłe;k Mopka.png`, that results in a valid response header:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename="Ty_ek; Mopka.png"; filename*=UTF-8''Ty%C5%82ek%3B%20Mopka.png
```

We've got here: a non ISO-8859-1 character, a space, a semicolon. The last one is especially interesting, not only because of parameters splitting, but also because of percent encoding (`decodeURI` is not enough, we need to `unescape` it).

#### Solution

```ts
export function parseContentDispositionFilename(contentDisposition: string): string {
  const filename = getFilename(contentDisposition);
  if (filename) {
    return unescape(decodeURI(filename));
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('content-disposition filename cannot be empty');
  }
}

function getFilename(contentDisposition: string): string | undefined {
  const filenames = getFilenameParams(contentDisposition);

  if (filenames.filenamestar) {
    // RFC 6266 4.1 filename* -> RFC 5987 3.2.1 ext-value
    return filenames.filenamestar.replace(/^(?<charset>.+)'(?<language>.*)'(?<filename>.+)$/, '$<filename>');
  }
  else if (filenames.filename) {
    // RFC 6266 4.1 filename (possibly quoted)
    return filenames.filename.replace(/^"(?<filename>.+)"$/, '$<filename>');
  }
  else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

function getFilenameParams(contentDisposition: string): { filenamestar?: string, filename?: string } {
  // Split using ; (if not quoted) and skip the first element since it's `disposition-type`
  const [, ...dispositionParams] = contentDisposition.split(/(?!\B"[^"]*);\s(?![^"]*"\B)/);
  return {
    filenamestar: getParamValue('filename\\*', dispositionParams),
    filename: getParamValue('filename', dispositionParams),
  };
}

function getParamValue(paramName: string, params: string[]): string | undefined {
  const regex = new RegExp('^\\s*' + paramName + '=(?<paramValue>.+)\\s*$', 'i');
  return params.find(p => p.match(regex)?.groups?.['paramValue']);
}
```

#### Usage

```ts
this.http.get(/*...*/).pipe(
  map(response => {
    const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('content-disposition');
    if (!contentDisposition) {
      throw new Error('content-disposition header not found');
    }

    const filename = parseContentDispositionFilename(contentDisposition);

/*...*/
```

Answer (score 0):

(file gets saved in binary format in the browser. the filename is in client's Network/header/Content-Disposition, we need to fetch the filename)

```
In Server-side code:
node js code-
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers','Content-Disposition');
    response.download(outputpath,fileName);   

In client-side code:
1)appComponent.ts file
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
this.reportscomponentservice.getReportsDownload(this.myArr).subscribe((event: any) => {
 var contentDispositionData= event.headers.get('content-disposition');
 let filename = contentDispositionData.split(";")[1].split("=")[1].split('"')[1].trim()
 saveAs(event.body, filename); 
});

2) service.ts file
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
getReportsDownload(myArr): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
 console.log('Service Page', myArr);
 return this.http.post(PowerSimEndPoints.GET_DOWNLOAD_DATA.PROD, myArr, {
  observe: 'response',
  responseType: 'blob'
 });
}
```