# How to get file name from content-disposition

Tags: javascript, ajax, filenames, file-type, content-disposition

I downloaded a file as response of ajax. How to get the file name and file type from `content-disposition` and display thumbnail for it. I got many search results but couldn't find right way.

```js
$(".download_btn").click(function () {
  var uiid = $(this).data("id2");

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/prj/" + data + "/" + uiid + "/getfile",
    type: "GET",
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
      var header = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
      console.log(header);     
    }
});
```

Console output:

```
inline; filename=demo3.png
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Why are you setting `window.location.href ="http://localhost:8080/prj/" + data + "/" + uiid + "/getfile";`? That will cause the browser to leave the page and just show that URL. How do you expect to display a thumbnail for the image if you have left the page? Why do you need the file name that the server suggests you save the file as in order to generate a thumbnail?

Comment: Getting the file name from the content-disposition is one problem. You can't get the file type from it, at least not reliably, that is what the content-type header is for. The thumbnail display would come from the data and is an entirely separate problem.

Comment: i need file name to display near thumbnail.

Comment: but i could find file type from filename itself  `filename.jpg`

Comment: if i could get file name i can get its extension and find if it is an image or not.
files are stored in server as base64encoded string in text file.content type is  always set to `application/x-msdownload` as single api is handling download of all file types.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Here is how I used it sometime back.
I'm assuming you are providing the attachment as a server response.

I set the response header like this from my REST service `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=XYZ.csv");`

```
function(response, status, xhr){
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
          filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Editing the answer to suit your question- use of the word `inline` instead of `attachment`

```
function(response, status, xhr){
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('inline') !== -1) {
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
          filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }
    }
}
```

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Comment: what does `filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');` do?

Comment: This solution will not work with cases like this: **attachment; filename*=UTF-8''filename.txt**.
Using this Regex, the filename will be **UTF-8filename.txt**.

Comment: I can't believe how knarly and ugly JavaScript is at times ...

Comment: To match utf8 pattern like this also: `dis = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''filename.pdf"` try `/filename\*?=([^']*'')?([^;]*)/.exec(dis)[2]`

Comment: I think it would be better to use `disposition.startsWith("attachment")` instead of `disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1`, since the filename may contain an _attachment_

Comment: `(filename\*=UTF-8''|filename=)(.+\b)`

Answer (score 44):

This is an improvement on marjon4's answer.

A much simplified way to the selected answer would be to use split like this;

```
var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split('filename=')[1].split(';')[0];
```

Note: This solution may not work as expected if your file name itself contains a semi-colon (;)

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the filename as a semicolon in it?

Comment: This is a naive approach, do not recommend. This could return incorrect results if the filename contains semicolons. Missing support for `filename*=UTF-8''`.

Comment: The solution works fine with ```filename*=UTF-8' '``` format The entire format you probably are referring to goes like this ```content-disposition: "attachment; filename=document.pdf; filename*=UTF-8''document.pdf"```. Please try to understand and answer before saying it won't work! And yes, for all technicality, this solution won't work if the file name itself has semi-colons. But in most cases, the file name doesn't include semi-colons so it has worked fine for me with this pretext in mind! (Still adding a note for that in my answer.)

Comment: Nor will it work for en edge-case when the filename itself contains `filename=`.

Comment: I would add .replaceAll('"',''), otherwise it seems to fail with spaced names

Answer (score 33):

If you want to get the filename and support both those weird url encoded UTF-8 headers and the ascii headers, you can use something like this

```js
public getFileName(disposition: string): string {
    const utf8FilenameRegex = /filename\*=UTF-8''([\w%\-\.]+)(?:; ?|$)/i;
    const asciiFilenameRegex = /^filename=(["']?)(.*?[^\\])\1(?:; ?|$)/i;

    let fileName: string = null;
    if (utf8FilenameRegex.test(disposition)) {
      fileName = decodeURIComponent(utf8FilenameRegex.exec(disposition)[1]);
    } else {
      // prevent ReDos attacks by anchoring the ascii regex to string start and
      //  slicing off everything before 'filename='
      const filenameStart = disposition.toLowerCase().indexOf('filename=');
      if (filenameStart >= 0) {
        const partialDisposition = disposition.slice(filenameStart);
        const matches = asciiFilenameRegex.exec(partialDisposition );
        if (matches != null && matches[2]) {
          fileName = matches[2];
        }
      }
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. this will take the value of the UTF-8 filename, if set, over the ascii name
2. on download, your browser may further alter the name to replace certain characters, like `"`, with `_` (Chrome)
3. the ascii pattern works best for quoted file names, but supports unquoted values. In that case it treats all text after the `filename=` and before the either the next `;` or the end of the header value as the file name.
4. This does not clean up path information. If you are saving the file from a website, that's the browser's job, but if your using this in the context of a node app or something similar, be sure to clean up the path information per the OS and leave just the filename, or a crafted file name might be used to overwrite a system file (think of a file name like `../../../../../../../path/to/system/files/malicious.dll`)

[MDN Content Disposition Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: The ASCII file name doesn't have to be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Comment: @MoonStom That's a good point, I'll update.

Comment: This is a great answer, I just had to make one change and add `i` to the end of the first regex because my header was coming back as `filename*=utf-8` not `UTF-8`.

Comment: The `dot` and `hyphen` do not need to be escaped in a character set in this instance.  So use `[.-]` instead of `[\.\-]`

Comment: I didn't know that, but I'm also of the opinion that special characters should be escaped even if they are not special characters in that context; it makes the code more readable, which I favor even outside of Stack Overflow

Comment: Note that the ASCII version seems to be vulnerable to a ReDos attack according to https://devina.io/redos-checker.

Answer (score 18):

In my case the header looks like this:

```
attachment; filename="test-file3.txt"
```

Therefore I was able to extract the filename pretty easily with a named group regexp:

```
const regExpFilename = /filename="(?<filename>.*)"/;

const filename: string | null = regExpFilename.exec(contentDispositionHeader)?.groups?.filename ?? null;
```

I know I'm slightly off topic here as OP doesn't have the quotes around the filename but still sharing in case someone comes across the same pattern as I just did

Answer (score 14):

Or simply just:

```
var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split("filename=")[1];
```

Comment: Not going to work with the following format: `content-disposition: "attachment; filename=document.pdf; filename*=UTF-8''document.pdf"`

Comment: Added an answer to address the problem mentioned by @AlexM

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
var contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
var startIndex = contentDisposition.indexOf("filename=") + 10; // Adjust '+ 10' if filename is not the right one.
var endIndex = contentDisposition.length - 1; //Check if '- 1' is necessary
var filename = contentDisposition.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
console.log("filename: " + filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also library [content-disposition-attachment](https://github.com/lujjjh/content-disposition-attachment), which can be used in the browser:

```
npm i -D content-disposition-attachment
```

```js
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { parse } from "content-disposition-attachment";

const getFilenameFromHeaders = ({ headers }: AxiosResponse<Blob>) => {
  const defaultName = "untitled";
  try {
    const { attachment, filename } = parse(headers["content-disposition"]);
    return attachment ? filename : defaultName;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return defaultName;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The below also takes into account scenarios where the `filename` includes unicode characters (i.e.,`-, !, (, )`, etc.) and hence, comes (`utf-8` encoded) in the form of, for instance, `filename*=utf-8''Na%C3%AFve%20file.txt` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) for more details). In such cases, the [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function is used to decode the `filename`.

```js
const disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
filename = disposition.split(/;(.+)/)[1].split(/=(.+)/)[1]
if (filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("utf-8''"))
    filename = decodeURIComponent(filename.replace("utf-8''", ''))
else
    filename = filename.replace(/['"]/g, '')
```

If you are doing a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request, make sure to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition` to the response headers on server side (see [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)), in order to expose the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header; otherwise, the `filename` won't be accessible on client side through JavaScript. For instance:

```py
headers = {'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'}
return FileResponse("Naïve file.txt", filename="Naïve file.txt", headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will help!

```
let filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1].split('.')[0];
let extension = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('.')[1].split(';')[0];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are **not working with multipart body** then you can use this function. It extracts the filename from the Content-Disposition header value (string like: *inline; filename=demo3.png*) and decodes as needed.

```
const getFileNameFromContentDisposition = disposition => { 
    if (disposition
        && (disposition.startsWith('attachment') || disposition.startsWith('inline'))
    ) {
        let filename = disposition.startsWith('attachment')
            ? disposition.replace("attachment;", "")
            : disposition.replace("inline;", ""); //replaces first match only
        filename = filename.trim();
        if (filename.includes("filename*=") && filename.includes("filename=")) {
            let filenames = filename.split(";"); //we can parse by ";" because all ";"s inside filename are escaped
            if (filenames.length > 1) { //"filename=" or "filename*=" not inside filename
                if (filenames[0].trim().startsWith("filename*=")) { //"filename*=" is preferred
                    filename = filenames[0].trim();
                } else {
                    filename = filenames[1].trim();
                }
            }
        }
        if (filename.startsWith("filename*=")) {
            filename = filename.replace("filename*=", "")
            .split("''").slice(1).join("''"); //remove encoding and ''
            filename = decodeURIComponent(filename);
        } else if (filename.startsWith("filename=")) {
            filename = filename.replace("filename=", "")
            if (filename.startsWith('"') && filename.endsWith('"')) {
                filename = filename.slice(1, filename.length - 1); //remove quotes
            }
        }
        return filename;
    }
}
```

The result of the function can be split into name and extension as follows:

```
let name = getFileNameFromContentDisposition("inline; filename=demo.3.png").split(".");
let extension = name[name.length - 1];
name = name.slice(0, name.length - 1).join(".");
console.log(name); // demo.3
console.log(extension); //png
```

You can display thumbnail, for example, using svg:

```
let colors = {"png": "red", "jpg": "orange"};
//this is a simple example, you can make something more beautiful
let createSVGThumbnail = extension => `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 20">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="18" height="20" fill = "#FAFEFF"/>
    <rect x="0" y="7" width="18" height="6" stroke="${colors[extension] || "blue"}" fill = "${colors[extension] || "blue"}"/>
    <text stroke = "white" fill = "white" font-size = "6" x = "0" y = "12.5" textLength = "18">${extension.toUpperCase()}</text>
</svg>`;

...

//You can use it as HTML element background-image
let background = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(new TextDecoder().decode(createSVGThumbnail("png")));
```

Comment: You should check if there are any quotes before you remove them. Even your own example disposition header doesn't use any quotes. Also it's common for the disposition header to include both "filename=" AND "filename=*" for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Indeed, I did not consider everything. Corrected answer