# Cant see headers of http post [Angular4]

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

This is something that should be easy to fix but right know my mind can't find a solution.

I've got a post like this:

```
getAccordo(filtro: Filter): Observable<Response>  {
    return this.http.post<Response>(`${this.ENDPOINT}/export`,
        filtro,
        {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}   
    )
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

And this is where I use it:

```
  public getAccordo(event: any): any {debugger;
    event.preventDefault();
    this.accordiService.getAccordo(this.filter).subscribe(
      res => {debugger;
        const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        anchor.download = Utils.extractHeaders(res);
        anchor.click();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

When I look the chrome console I can see that in the headers there is a `content-disposition: attachment; filename="esportazione_accordi_20180905.xlsx"`

But in my 'res' this is missing.

[image: Res]

What id like to do is to get the filename and use it in anchor.download.

Thank you for the help if you need something more just ask.

**EDIT**

This is the headers that i get from the Response Headers, I dont see even 1 of them:

[image]

On the server side ive added: `.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "content-disposition")`  But still it doesnt work

EDIT 2:

Ok we are getting closer, I need to get the "filename" value at the end of the pic and assign that to anchor.download.

[image]

Comment: The response headers are *lazily parsed* - You'll need to actually attempt to get the header using `res.headers.get('Content-Disposition')` to see a result.

Comment: ok so if I use res.headers.get('Content-Disposition') i get everything, one last step, how can i use the value that i need? Ill update the post again in a min to show you what i mean

Comment: You can use regex for that - here's a really basic example: `const filename = /attachment; filename="(.+")/.exec(headerValue)[1];`. This assumes the regex is going to match - you can check the return value of the `exec` call for `null` before accessing it's second array element to be safe here.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939380/how-to-get-file-name-from-content-disposition)'s another question specifically on that filename parsing stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to *expose* this header to your Angular XHR, the *server* will need to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header to allow specifically access to the `Content-Disposition` header. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) have more information on the subject:

> By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to list them using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

This means that your server needs to set the following header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
```

In Angular, using `HttpClient`, the response headers are *lazily parsed* - To get a specific header's value, you'll need to to `get` the header using something like this:

```
res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
```