# ASP.NET Core busy indicator while downloading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

On my web page when a user clicks the download button the Exports Action is called from the controller, an Excel file is generated and then returned to the user. Depending on the parameters passed to the action it sometimes takes some time for the file to be generated and returned to the user.

So, I want to show a busy indicator while waiting for the file. I went with Bootstrap spinner.

```js
$('.content').on('click', 'a.export', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // show busy indicator
    $('#divSpinner').css('display', 'inline-block');

    var idSelect = '';
    $('#ddlSelect option:selected').each(function () {
        idSelect += $('#ddlSelect')[0].value;
    });

    var idSelect2 = '';
    $('#ddlSelect2 option:selected').each(function () {
        idSelect2 += $('#ddlSelect2')[0].value;
    });

    var url = 'Home/Exports?' + 'param1=' + idSelect + '&param2=' + idSelect2;

    //download file
    window.location = url;

    // hide busy indicator
    $('#divSpinner').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Well this kind of works, but the problem is that **$('#divSpinner').css('display', 'none');** gets hit immediately and the spinner hides before the file is actually available to the user for download (browser download/open window).

How can I rewrite the code to wait for **window.location=url** to finish and then hide the spinner?

**EDIT:**
I also tried wrapping the Download part in an async function like this:

```js
async function Download(url) {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(window.location = url);
    });

        let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)
}
```

and calling it like this:

```js
Download(url)
    .then(function() {
        $('#divSpinner').hide()
});
```

Download works, but still `$('#divSpinner').hide()` get's hit before the file download is presented to the user. Isn't the whole point of async/await to wait for the result before continuing code execution??

**EDIT2 (with "blob"):**

```js
async function Download(url) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(filedownload(url));
    });
    let result = await promise; 
}

function filedownload(urlToSend) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", urlToSend, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;
        var fileName = req.getResponseHeader("fileName") 
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
    };
    req.send();
}
```

and calling it like this:

```js
Download(url)
    .then(function() {
        $('#divSpinner').hide()
});
```

**EDIT 3**: I used @Nenad's solution from below, but I only changed the handling of the response header (otherwise I was getting NULL for filename at download - I used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940790/7975627):

```js
function filedownload(urlToSend, resolve) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", urlToSend, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;    
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
        }
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
        resolve(filename); // call resolve after download has finished.
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: Is this function calling from the same page? from /Home/Exports ?

Comment: By the way, your <hide busy indicator> won't work. Because you are changing the page before it. So I guess you need to make your indicator visible at startup. When excel data came up, you will hide the indicator.

Comment: Yes, the View and Controller are both "Home" (Action Exports is also in Home controller). Also javascript/jquery is part of the "Index.cshtml" of the Home view

Comment: @cbalakus: <hide busy indicator works>. The problem is that it get hidden to quickly (practically instantly, because the code doesnt stop at 'window.location' but continues to the end and after the file is ready the user is prompted for save/oen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You are delegating control to the browser, so there is ***no JavaScript notification*** on your page of a finished process.

**In detail:**

The method you use to download file (`window.location = url;`) tells to the browser to load a new page instead of the current one. You are delegating control of loading of a new page to the browser, same like if `url` would point to another HTML page.

Only after browser figures that content is not HTML, but something else, based on headers, it downloads the file, instead of throwing current page and displaying new one.

Headers that direct browser to download the content are:

- `content-disposition: attachment`
- `content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

**Different approach** would be to use AJAX request to download `responseType=blob`.
 Good example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815974/186822). Drawbacks of this method are:

- It's not supported in older browsers.
- Full file is loaded JavaScript memory, before you save it.

But you have control of what is happening after the `blob` download
   has completed.

UPDATE: Looking at your 2nd edit, you are calling `resolve` to early. Also, you should return your `Promise` from download method.

```js
async function Download(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        filedownload(url, resolve); // pass resolve
    }); 
}

function filedownload(urlToSend, resolve) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", urlToSend, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;
        var fileName = req.getResponseHeader("fileName") 
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        resolve(fileName); // call resolve after download has finished.
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: I tried using the ajax function from your link and putting it in my "resolve(...)", but still there are 2 problems: 1) `$('#divSpinner').css('display', 'none');`  still gets hit immediately and 2) my download filename is NULL (from the controller I'm returning file like this: `return File(file.Contents, file.ContentType, file.Title);`)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC part has nothing to do with behavior in browser, unless you are doing something completely wrong. This is JavaScript issue. Post your solution with Blob as new edit to the question.

Comment: Hello. Any other ideas?

Comment: You are calling `resolve` way to early. It should be called after `link.click` in the `filedownload` function. Use `filedownload(urlToSend, resolve)` and call `resolve` after `link.click`.

Comment: Thank you! Solved with a minor modification for avoiding NULL filename (see my edit3 above)

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'Home/Exports?' + 'param1=' + idSelect + '&param2=' + idSelect2;

$(document).load(url, function () {
    // hide busy indicator
    $('#divSpinner').css('display', 'none');
});
```

I'm not sure but, can you try this?

Comment: this way file download doesnt work... spinner shows for a few seconds and then disappears, but no file download is offered to the user