# Http Response headers missing in chrome, but with Postman they show up

Tags: rest, angular

When calling my REST Service in Angular, there are no response headers.

**Login method in Angular**

```js
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const credentials = { "username": username, "password": password };
    return this.http.post(this.url, credentials)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data), // JSON.stringify(data.headers) also is empty
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

**Output in the Chrome dev tools console**

> Response {_body: "", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers:
>   Headers…}headers: Headers_headers: Map(0)_normalizedNames:
>   Map(0)**proto**: Objectok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 2url:
>   "http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/login"_body: ""**proto**: Body

But when I send the same post request with postman, I get the expected result:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Authorization →Bearer eyJ[...]
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →0
Date →Mon, 12 Jun 2017 13:19:54 GMT
Server →WildFly/10
Vary →Origin
X-Powered-By →Undertow/1
```

**The REST Service**

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateUser(CredentialsDTO credentialsDTO) {
    try {
        authService.login(credentialsDTO.getUsername(), credentialsDTO.getPassword());
    } catch (WrongCredentialsException e) {

        return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("WrongCredentialsException").build();
    } 

    // Issue token
    String token = issueToken(credentialsDTO.getUsername());

    // Return the token on the response
    return Response.ok().header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token).build();
}
```

**Why can't I see the headers in chrome ?**

**UPDATE**
I am also using a CORSFilter that allowed Javascript to contact my backend in the first place. This is how it is configured in my web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Although I thought it was configured to allow everything, I am not sure if this is related to my problem.

Comment: data is a resposne object, you should do console.log(data.headers) to see them, or maybe JSON.stringify them in the log if you can't see them.

Comment: I had tried that - but the headers are empty.

Comment: what header are you expecting ? is it a CORS request ? I guess `Authorization` and yes...

Comment: I am trying to read the Authorization header in order to get the Bearer (JWT Token) Also, I was expecting to see all headers that I see in Postman

Comment: **is it a CORS request ?**

Comment: @n00dl3 You think this could be related with the fact that he is not sending headers in the `options` parameters of `.post()`?

Comment: Yes it is. But I am using a CORSFilter that allows everything

Comment: @SrAxi I also tried sending the Content-Type application/json with my request.

Comment: @SrAxi no. @Tim your server is not sending an [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) set to `Authorization` so it is not available to js.

Comment: @Tim Are you allowing POST method? `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST'`.

Comment: @SrAxi if it was disallowed, there would be no response at all.

Comment: @n00dl3 Wouldn't you get "access denied" response? However, you are right.

Comment: I updated my question with my CORS config. When trying to set the  Access-Control-Expose-Headers manually, it tells me that it is already set, so I assume that my CORS Filter already sets it. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Tim: `<init-param><param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name><param-value>Authorization</param-value><init-param>`

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly it. Add the answer and I'll accept it right away. Also, I found this article to be very informative: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/ I guess I still have a few things to learn.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default CORS responses only exposes these 6 headers to scripts:

- `Cache-Control`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type`
- `Expires`
- `Last-Modified`
- `Pragma`

To allow scripts to access other headers sent by the sever, the server needs to send the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) Header.

> The Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header indicates which headers can be exposed to scripts as part of the response by listing their names.

eg: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization, X-Foobar`

You can tweak your `web.xml` file including this to allow the `Authorization` header to be accessed from the script that made the XHR:

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
  <par‌​am-value>Authorizati‌​on</param-value>
<ini‌​t-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution to allow my custom header in Owin self-hosted web api

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Cors;

namespace App.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class CorsConfig
    {
        public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var allowedOrigins = "comma,separated,list,of,origins";
            var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
            {
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                AllowAnyOrigin = false,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };

            corsPolicy.ExposedHeaders.Add("Custom-Header");

            foreach (string origin in allowedOrigins.Split(','))
                corsPolicy.Origins.Add(origin);

            app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

I call the method like this CorsConfig.Configure(app); // app is Owin.IAppBuilder

Answer (score 0):

The headers in an HttpResponse object are lazy-loaded, so `headers` will appear to be empty until you force the values to be loaded. Try calling `response.headers.keys()` to see all available header names. By the way, this also forces all values to be loaded into the map `response.headers.headers`.

Be sure to use `headers.get('my-header-name')` if you only need to access one particular header value.