# Empty HTTP response headers in browser but filled in POSTMAN

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http-headers, httpwebresponse

I've created a Spring Boot back end with a React front end.

- When I'm sending a HTTP request via browser to my backend, I receive a
  response with empty headers.

  - [Browser response with empty headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A56FG.jpg)
- When I'm sending a HTTP request via the POSTMAN tool, I got filled headers!

  - [POSTMAN response with fullfilled headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCDNl.jpg)

That doesn't make sense to me.

**Code:** https://github.com/The-Taskmanager/SelfServiceWebwizard

*Back end Mapping*

```
@PostMapping("/signin")

public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                    loginRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Mustermann", "Max");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Authorization", new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt).getAccessToken());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));

}
```

*Front end request*

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "usernameOrEmail": username,
            "password": password
        })
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.text());
        console.log(response.headers);
    })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

**UPDATE1:**
Added this method but headers in browser still empty:

```
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

When I request with React, Spring Boot shows me this ERROR:

```
ERROR 8876 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.s.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint:  Responding with unauthorized error. Message - full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Browser console:

[image: browser console]

When I request with Postman, Spring Boot shows no ERROR.

**UPDATE3:**

Request-header send by React:

```
{
host=[localhost:8080],
content-type=[application/json],
cache-control=[no-cache],
user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0],
accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate],
content-length=[58],
referer=[http://localhost:8080/],
origin=[http://localhost:8080],
dnt=[1],
connection=[keep-alive],
accept-language=[de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3],
accept=[*/*]
}
```

Request-header send by POSTMAN from POSTMAN console:

```
host:"localhost:8080"
content-type:"application/json"
cache-control:"no-cache"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.5"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:68
postman-token:"b00fd7a8-bd34-4a32-8681-990b04012e3b"
cookie:"JSESSIONID=2CAEC9280432DD13AABA53B73B7874AC"
accept:"*/*"
```

Comment: This might be the same problem as yours. I cannot current test this myself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501476/http-response-headers-missing-in-chrome-but-with-postman-they-show-up

Comment: Try and add the following. Input the headers you want to expose - seperated by a comma. `headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization, Ziethen, OtherCustomHeaders...");`

Comment: @kkflf Thank you. Done, but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Okay. Sorry, then I cannot help you. The other stackoverflow post looked very similar to yours. I have not worked with react before, but I assume it received the headers, but does not explose the header to the browser. Is it important to view the header in the browser?

Comment: @kkflf I wanted to store a JSON token in the header. I don't think that React doesn't manage to show the headers in the browser, I think React doesn't receive a response with headers after it's request. Because when i try to parse the response in React, i got an JSON parsing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself.

Changed code in front end's fetch method

```
console.log(response.headers)

// changed to:

console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization')
```

So the headers were there all the time but I couldn't manage to log them in browser console with React.

Nevertheless there is the Spring Boot (full authentication) and Browser (401) error in **UPDATE2**. Don't know where this is coming from.